# Stored procedure parameters to R

Tags: sql-server, r, microsoft-r

I am trying to run a simple R sum in R-Services using the parameters handed to a stored procedure but I do not know how to do it, nor find a good example. This is what I have so far:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'TEST', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL   
    DROP PROCEDURE TEST;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST @a int = 0, @b int = 0 AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
    ,@script = N'print(sum(@a, @b))' -- how to pass params here?
    ,@input_data_1 = N'@a'
    return @a + @b;
END

EXEC dbo.TEST @a = 2, @b = 3
GO
```

My question is how to pass the variables read in the stored procedure (`@a` and `@b`) to the R script?

Comment: What does your current `EXEC` call return? An error? No results?

Comment: The message is: Msg 214, Level 16, State 179, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, Line 1 Procedure expects parameter '@input_data_1' of type 'nvarchar(max)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `@params` to pass SQL Server params to R variables as shown in this [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-using-r-functions-with-sql-server-data). Be sure to always return a dataframe object and leave `@input_data_1` for SQL Server queries that you need passed into R script in the *InputDataSet* dataframe object (hence it is blank here).

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc (@a int, @b int)
AS
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script    
      @language = N'R'    
    , @script = N' OutputDataSet <- data.frame(SumRes = sum(a_r, b_r));'    
    , @input_data_1 = N'   ;' 
    , @params = N' @a_r int, @b_r int'  
    , @a_r = @a
    , @b_r = @b
    WITH RESULT SETS (([SumResult] int NOT NULL));
```

And then call procedure:

```
EXEC dbo.myProc @a = 2, @b = 3
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It works, but I had to remove the @ in the  R script to make it (SumRes = sum(a_r, b_r)) Please edit the answer when it best suits you.

Comment: Indeed...sorry for that small overlook! Thanks @HongOoi for the edit. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

run below query

```
EXEC dbo.TEST 2,  3
```

Comment: How is it different from EXEC dbo.TEST @a = 2, @b = 3

Answer (score 0):

```
Field1 <- 'fd'
Field2 <- '20'
query <- paste0(
  "exec df_test @Name = ", Field1, ", @ProductNumber = ", Field2, ""
)
sqlQuery(cn, query)
odbcClose(cn)
```

Execute your stored procedure like this for r code

Happy Coding... :)